# IF in VBA with multiple OR and AND

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to translate one of my excel if condition into vba but I do not able.

The condition is the following If `C2` equal `TextA` and `M2` equal `Text1`, or C2 equal TextA and M2 equal Text2, or C2 equal TextB, then I want to get a result in cell AA2=0, in any other case AA="27B"

And I would like to run this in every cell where C2 is not empty.
I solved in excel:

```
=IF(OR(AND(C2="tgk",M2="Éves kártyadíj"),AND(C2="tgk",M2="EMATRICA D2 HETI")),"0",IF(C2="szgk","0","27B"))
```

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: Sorry Jeeped, it looks so fine, however it gave me an error, because in the second row .cells is invalid. I am very beginner , and I do not know what i need to change to work.Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Simplest thing would probably to use Application.WorksheetFunction and use the formula that already works in the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your challenge, the following should work in VBA...

```
If ((Range("C2").Value = "tgk") And (Range("M2").Value = "Éves kártyadíj" Or Range("M2").Value = "EMATRICA D2 HETI")) Then
Range("AA2").Value = 0
ElseIf Range("C2").Value = "szgk" Then
Range("AA2").Value = 0
Else: Range("AA2").Value = "27B"
End If
```